How to get the height of a SwiftUI view if the content might change?
I tried like this:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var contentHeight: CGFloat = .zero

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Dynamic Content")
            Spacer()
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                Color.clear.preference(
                    key: ViewHeightKey.self,
                    value: geometry.size.height
                )
            }
            .onPreferenceChange(ViewHeightKey.self) { height in
                self.contentHeight = height
            }
            .background(Color.red) // Optional background color for visualization
        }
        .frame(height: contentHeight)
        .border(Color.blue) // Optional border for visualization
    }
}

struct ViewHeightKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGFloat = 0
    static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat, nextValue: () -> CGFloat) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}

But got this error:

Cannot find 'ViewHeightKey' in scope


One technique is to use a GeometryReader in the background of the view you want to measure. A PreferenceKey is not needed, you can just update a state variable instead.
Here is a little demo to show it working.

The height of the blue rectangle can be adjusted with the slider.
The total height of the red frame is read using a GeometryReader in the background behind it.
An .onChange handler is used to update a state variable on initial show and whenever the height changes.
The dynamic height that is measured is applied to the green rectangle.

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var dynamicContentHeight: CGFloat = .zero
    @State private var blueContentHeight: CGFloat = 100

    private var heightReader: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            let h = proxy.size.height
            Color.clear
                .onChange(of: h, initial: true) { oldVal, newVal in
                    dynamicContentHeight = newVal
                }
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            VStack {
                Text("Height of blue rectangle: \(String(format: "%.0f", blueContentHeight))")
                    .padding(.vertical)
                Color.blue
                    .frame(width: 300, height: blueContentHeight)
            }
            .border(.red, width: 2)
            .background(heightReader)

            Color.green
                .overlay(Text("Height matched to red frame"))
                .foregroundStyle(.white)
                .frame(width: 300, height: dynamicContentHeight)

            Spacer()
            Slider(value: $blueContentHeight, in: 0...200, step: 1)
                .padding(40)
        }
    }
}


This code uses a version of .onChange that was introduced in iOS 17.0. For earlier iOS versions, it can be done like this instead:
private var heightReader: some View {
    GeometryReader { proxy in
        let h = proxy.size.height
        Color.clear
            .onAppear {
                dynamicContentHeight = h
            }
            .onChange(of: h) { newVal in
                dynamicContentHeight = newVal
            }
    }
}


When I implement this pattern in our visionPro app, onChange in heightReader will not get called, do you know why?

In my case height is not set by controller, but user change one of the window in Vision Pro.

@János I have no idea, sorry. But this technique is usually robust and reliable when applied to pure SwiftUI views. Make sure you include initial: true if you're using the verion for iOS 17.0+.

I found a similar way to calculate height via background:
private func viewHeight(for binding: Binding<CGFloat>) -> some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry -> Color in
        let rect = geometry.frame(in: .local)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            binding.wrappedValue = rect.size.height
        }
        return .clear
    }
}

For example use it like this:
@State var titleLayoutHeihgt: CGFloat = .zero

.....

Text("Title")
    .font(.title)
    .background(viewHeight(for: $titleLayoutHeihgt))

This function was founded here:
https://blog.logrocket.com/implementing-tags-swiftui/
